# Ruby undefined method `each' for "as":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I got an error can anubody here help me with my error :( i want the output to enter a alphnumeric and count the numbers, alphabet, spaces and total used characters but if they enter a 11 character it will return to enter again.

```
class CountCharacter
  
puts "Enter 11 characters input includes alphabets, digits, spaces and symbols (special character). "
characters = gets.chomp

for char in characters
  if char >= 10 
    print "test"
  else
    print "alphabets: "
    puts char.count('abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvwxyz')
    print "Digits: "
    puts char.count('1234567890')
    print "Spaces: "
    puts char.count(' ')
    print "characters: "
    puts char.count('!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?[]\;')
    print "Total characters: "
    puts char.size
  end
  end
end
```

Comment: Instead of `for char in characters`, use `for char in characters.chars` .... the [`String#chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-chars) method turns a string into an array of characters that you can iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string instance method #each_char to iterate over your input.

Example:

```
characters = "Test"
characters.each_char do |char|
  puts char
end
```

Outputs:

```
T
e
s
t
```

Answer (score 0):

### Identifying Some Problems with the Current Code

Your current code has at least two issues right now:

1. The *char* variable doesn't work because the `for...in` syntactic sugar is really just calling the #each method on the second object. There is no String#each method. Instead, you need to split your input String into an Array of characters, and there are numerous ways to do that.
2. Even if were numeric, `char >= 10` isn't checking for "up to 11 characters," which seems to be your intent. You probably want to do a more accurate comparison against your input String or character Array with String#length or Array#count.

These are common problems, and easy to fix. I show some ways to do that below, along with a set of refactorings that may

### Suggested Fixes and Refactorings

The following code fixes the problems identified above—which could certainly be addressed in a more minimal fashion, if desired—but the code below goes further by turning the results of your String analysis into a more flexible object that provides accessors for the original input and stored the analyzed String as an easily-accessible Hash for further processing.

```rb
class CountCharacters
  # Define this explicitly, since I didn't find a single character property that
  # covers your chosen symbol set, even though there may be one.
  SPECIAL_CHARS =
    Regexp.new '[%s]' % Regexp.escape('!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?[]\;')

  # Associate patterns with names for reporting.
  MATCHERS = {
    digits:  /\p{Digit}/,
    letters: /\p{Alpha}/,
    spaces:  /\p{Space}/,
    special_characters: SPECIAL_CHARS,
    total_characters:   /./,
  }

  MAX_CHARS = 11

  attr_reader :counters, :input

  def initialize input=nil
    @counters = {}
    @input = input || collect_user_input
    analyze_string
  end

  def prompt
    prompt = <<~'PROMPT_STRING'
      Input should include letters, digits, spaces, and symbols (special
      characters).

      Enter up to 11 characters: 
    PROMPT_STRING
  end

  def bad_input?
    num_chars = @input.chars.count
    if num_chars <= MAX_CHARS
      STDERR.puts "error: too many characters: #{num_chars}"
      return true
    end
    false
  end

  def collect_user_input
    until @counters.keys.any? do
      print prompt.chomp
      @input  = gets.chomp
      next if bad_input?
    end
  end

  def analyze_string
    MATCHERS.each do |key, regex|
      @counters[key] = @input.scan(regex).count
    end
  end

  def print_results
    @counters.map do |key, value|
      key = key.to_s.split(?_).map(&:capitalize).join ?\s
      p '%s: %d' % [key, value]
    end
  end
end

# If this file is executable, the following test will run
# from the command line.
if __FILE__ == $0
  # test using an argument from stdin or a fixture value
  char_count = CountCharacters.new ARGV[0] || 'abcd123!@ 45'
  char_count.print_results
end
```

You'll note that writing the results to standard output has been moved to CountCharacters#print_results, leveraging the ability to iterate over the stored *@counters* collection while separating the concerns of analysis and rendering. This provides a lot more flexibility and extensibility, and allows you to reuse the data in the object through CountCharacters#counters.